# ARCORE - when time will come for unsupported S8+

Tags: android, arcore

I have unsupported device for arcore - Sumsung Galaxy S8+ SM-G9550.
When it's supporting will come?

Just little story - I bought it a few days ago, specialy for ar development, in 
    `//second hand property`so it is unpossible to return it. I saw on forum way for pushing my phone in working behavier, but I am still interested in this info
=)

P.S.
As I understood, my phone from Honkong (zero in the end) - I am from Siberia (Russia).

Comment: Don't you think that's a better question to ask them directly?

Comment: I thought in that way and came to the arcore site for it:

>GitHub View current issues and report new ones using the issue tracker.

>Stack Overflow Ask questions and browse answers using the official arcore tag.

>AR Experiments Check out fun examples of what's possible with ARCore and share what you've built.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't tech support or customer service for ARCore.  Questions on how to use it are probably on topic-  depending on scope.  Questions about the state of the project should be on some mailing list/forum/other they own.

Comment: Okey, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ARCore-for-all until offical support comes: https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all